# Predicate logic problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

(a) ∀x∃y(P(x) ∧ Q(y)) ⇔ ∃x∀y(P(x) ∧ Q(y))
(b) ∀x∃y(P(x) → Q(y)) ⇔ ∃x∀y(P(x) → Q(y))
(c) ¬∀x(P(x) ∧ Q(x)) ⇔ ∃y(P(y) → ¬Q(y))

So with these questions im supposed to show that in each case the equivalency is true no matter what sets x and y are apart of. I can do that or show a counterargument. I need help badly if anyone knows how to solve these please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to proceed with any of them? When you've got as a hypothesis $\forall x P(x)$ the general procedure is choosing an arbitrary $a$ in your universe. If you've got in your hypothesis $\exists x P(x)$ then choose that $x$ (call it $a$ maybe) such that $P(a)$. If you want to prove that $\forall x P(x)$, choose and arbitrary $a$ and try to prove $P(a)$. Finally, if you want to proof $\exists x P(x)$ you should try by contradiction.

Comment: I did try this! Still didn't get anywhere with it. @Javi

Comment: @ChantMekhitarian Were you given, and can you use, any elementary equivalence principles involving quantifiers? For example, can you use Quantifier Negation, or Replace Variables?

Comment: @Bram28 What I've written above is all I got on the task, it doesnt say anything about not being able to use elementary quantifiers.

Comment: Hmm, but this must be part of some module?  Did your class or your book cover any such equivalence principles yet?  Or did you talk about semantics?  Or maybe you covered the tree method? Or ...? The point is, there are many ways to address and try and answer this question, but presumably it has to be done within the cvontext of the material you just learned. So what was the context of this question?  Are you using a book?

Comment: @Bram28 It did not, the text book explained predicates really bad. It was in Swedish though so I don't see any point trying to show you what it said haha.

Comment: @ChantMekhitarian I'll give you a clue. The first one is false, so you just have to find a counterexample.
And if there's any equivalence property in that book, you should use it whenever you can.

Comment: @ChantMekhitarian Hmm, ok, it sounds like you weren't given any syntactical tools then, so probably a more semantical method is in order. I'll post something to get you started.

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks alot for your help, really appreciate it. I need to hand this in in an hour and I really dont know how to get around B and C. If you want to save me (and my grade) could you please help me solve them? I would totally understand if you couldnt though and im really appreciative for your help this far!

Comment: @ChantMekhitarian Ah, well, I think it's really bad form to do other people's HW for them ... so I gave you this one, but you should really try and do the others yourself! Good luck!

Comment: @Bram28 I'll try, and ill post what i come up with here, if you could correct me if im wrong that'be great:)

Comment: @ChantMekhitarian OK, posting your own efforts is certainly very much encouraged and appreciated on this site!

Comment: I wonder, why you use ⇔, given that those are obviously opposite statements. As about (b), for making opposite, you need to negate implication in RHS.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS of (a) says that 'for every $x$ there is some $y$ such that $x$ has property $P$ and $y$ has property $y$.  Note that this implies that everything needs to have property $P$, but you really need only one thing to have property $Q$.

The RHS, however, says the 'opposite': for the RHS to be true everything needs to have property $Q$, but only one thing needs to have property $P$.

So, these are not saying the same thing ... and for a concrete counterexample, you just need two objects: if both objects have property $P$ but only one of them has property $Q$, then the LHS is true, but the RHS is false.

OK, can you try and do (b) and (c) like that?